# Is JavaScript Closure the Solution here, How to use it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, google-maps, closures

I have google maps implemented and I am getting latitude and longitude, I want thse values to be used outside of the google maps function. I can add them to the DOM only when I call these variables within the google maps code. How can I use these variables outside to google maps function.

On click of the maps, I need to append these latitude and longitude values to the URL as a querystring.

I am not sure how Closures work exactly. Can someone please help me adding these latitude and longitude values to the querystring outside of google maps initilaize() function.

Below is my code;

```
<script>
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.397, -122.644),
    zoom: 4,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(44.397, -122.644),
    map: map,
    draggable: true
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousemove', function ques(event) {
    var lat_value = event.latLng.lat();
    var lon_value = event.latLng.lng();
    document.getElementById("llat").value = lat_value;
    document.getElementById("llon").value = lon_value;
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function cclick() {
  })
}
</script>
<script>
$(function () {
  // Access functions and variables defined in google maps initialize() function here
  if(document.location.href.indexOf('?') == -1) {
    window.location = window.location + "?lat_value";
  }
});
</script>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/VzF4Q/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a JS closure here. You don't even need to write the handler outside of the scope of that `initialize` method. Just do it the same way you did the `mousemove` handler:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (e) {
    var lat_value = e.latLng.lat();
    var lon_value = e.latLng.lng();
    window.location = window.location.href.split('?')[0] 
      + "?lat_value=" + lat_value
      + "&long_value=" + lon_value;
});
```

In general though, if you wanted to have access to your `mapOptions` variable outside of initialize, just define it in the outer-scope (i.e. do the `var mapOptions` declaration before `function initialize`).

Comment: Thanks that's fine, I cant use this within initilaize function, I need to do in a separate function like <script>window.location = window.location.href.split('?')[0] 
      + "?lat_value=" + lat_value
      + "&long_value=" + lon_value;</script> but obviously these values wont be defined here so my problem arises. My question would be to how to use these variables outside of initiliaze function. Actually in a new script block.

Comment: @Mike The latitude and longitude values have to come from the map click event. They are generated when the user clicks the mouse button. The maps api doesn't provide a method for getting the LatLng object corresponding to screen coordinates, so you can't get it using a regular DOM click event. You don't have to do the processing within that method though: you can define a method somewhere else, and call it from inside the click handler and pass in `lat_value` and `long_value` as parameters. But that is functionally equivalent.

Comment: @Mike Perhaps if you explain your requirement some more I can be more helpful: what exactly are you trying to accomplish by dividing this up? Whether two methods are defined in the same script block or not is irrelevant to how they are processed.

Comment: I am building an APP, that uses a third party code a jQuery plugin. My APP is dependent on google maps lat lon values. For my APP to work correctly, I need the google maps to give me lat lon values that I can use in my code, so I would like to have lat lon values in a separate  script block where my plugin code is and not inside initialize function of maps.

I am trying to see if I can use my APP code inside the map click event. but it might cause inconsisties as I am learning javascript.

Comment: You can save Latitude and Longitude to a DOM element as data attribute. In simplest case, save it to body element whenever coordinates change: $('body').data('latitude', newVal)
Then you can trigger custom event to let the application know that coordinates changed. It's easier with Observe pattern but I don't know if you use any framework which supports that.

Comment: @nbrooks: I need to use the function onLoad() It says me onLoad is undefined on marker dragend, any ideas.  http://jsfiddle.net/gWjmh/2/